# How to get the total count between two values in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, window-functions

I have 3 activities in a single column `(completed_order, email, viewed)` and I want to count, how many `email` activities occurred in between each `completed_order` activity and save them in a different column.
I wrote this Query:

```
SELECT  activity_id, ts, customer, activity ,
        case when activity = 'completed_order'      
        then count(*)filter (where activity = 'email' ) over (partition by customer order by ts )
        else null end as Aggregate_in_between
    FROM public.activity_stream as az1  where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand' order by ts ;
```

And I am getting the below result with the above query.

| activity_id | ts | customer | activity | agg_in_btw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11089 | "1996-08-12 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 0 |
| 10279 | "1996-08-13 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 0 |
| 11077 | "1996-08-14 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11092 | "1996-08-17 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 11088 | "1996-08-18 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 10284 | "1996-08-19 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 1 |
| 11078 | "1996-08-20 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11079 | "1996-08-21 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11080 | "1996-10-21 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 10343 | "1996-10-31 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 4 |
| 11090 | "1996-11-01 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 11091 | "1996-11-02 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 10497 | "1997-04-04 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 5 |
| 10522 | "1997-04-30 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 5 |

My Desired Result should be like this

| activity_id | ts | customer | activity | agg_in_btw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11089 | "1996-08-12 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 0 |
| 10279 | "1996-08-13 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 1 |
| 11077 | "1996-08-14 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11092 | "1996-08-17 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 11088 | "1996-08-18 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 10284 | "1996-08-19 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 3 |
| 11078 | "1996-08-20 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11079 | "1996-08-21 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 11080 | "1996-10-21 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 10343 | "1996-10-31 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 1 |
| 11090 | "1996-11-01 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "viewed_page" |  |
| 11091 | "1996-11-02 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "email" |  |
| 10497 | "1997-04-04 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 0 |
| 10522 | "1997-04-30 00:00:00+05" | "Lehmanns Marktstand" | "completed_order" | 0 |

Comment: I have added the answer. hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select  activity_id, ts, customer, activity ,
case when activity = 'completed_order' then
sum(case when activity='email' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer,grp1)
else
null
end "Aggregate_in_between"
from (
select *, sum(grp) over (partition by customer order by ts) "grp1" from (
select *, case when activity='completed_order' then 1 else 0 end "grp" from activity_stream order by ts  
) t ) q
```

Here you have to create a group of each `completed_order` occurance and them count the `email` in each group.

you can add where clause as per your convenience

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e71d97d300a4d95733ebb42271ebc980)

Answer (score 0):

This is a grouping problem.  Assign a group based on the cumulative count of "completed".  Then count within each group:

```
select a.*,
       count(*) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by co_grp)
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where activity = 'completed_order') over (partition by customer order by ts) as co_grp
      from public.activity_stream a
      where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
     ) a
order by ts ;
```

In your example data, you seem to only want this on completed order rows, so use a `case` expression for that:

```
select a.*,
       (case when activity = 'completed_order'
             then count(*) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by co_grp)
        end) as agg_in_btw
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where activity = 'completed_order') over (partition by customer order by ts) as co_grp
      from public.activity_stream a
      where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
     ) a
order by ts ;
```